# Removing a deb package installed from thirdparty

Tags: apt, xubuntu, software-center

New to Linux and Xubuntu, I have recently installed Xubuntu  14.04 64 bit and so far I have been installing/uninstalling apps from the Ubunutu software center.

Recently I have installed google chrome since it was not available in the software center I downloaded from google's website.

It downloaded following file

```
 google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
```

When I double clicked to install it, it has opened the software center app and showing the page for chrome and an install button which I clicked to install it successfully.

I later on deleted the .deb file, now I want to remove the chrome from Xubuntu but When I open the Ubuntu software center and tap the installed button it shows all other apps but not the google chrome that I installed.

SO my question is how to remove any such app that I install using the downloaded .deb file from elsewhere and in this case chrome ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can remove any software installed via a .deb packages with the `apt-get remove` command

First open a terminal session with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and type in:

> sudo apt-get remove google-chrome-stable

This should remove the package from your system.

Additionally, to see a list of locally installed and obsolete packages either run the command

```
sudo apt-get install aptitude
aptitude search '~o'
```

or install `Synaptic` with `sudo apt-get install synaptic` and click on the `Status` button on the left panel and select `Installed (local or obsolete)`. See screen capture below for reference.

[image: Synaptic showing local and obsolete packages]

Both options will show you the list of all .deb installed packages.

Comment: So will I have to remember names of the packages that I install from outside ? is there a way to figure the external packages out by somehow listing them on terminal and then remove them ?

Comment: @Ahmed I have edited my answer to include ways of finding locally install packages.

Answer (score 2):

*Software center version of the answer*:

In the software center go to **Installed** and at this **Installed** button there is an arrow showing options - Tick the **Unknown** - there is a list of application you installed from outer places.

[image]